# Show Popup From Bottom-right

Tags: jquery, popup

I would like a popup to open from the bottom right of the browser/page. I have the html/css popup but dont know how to open it from bottom right of the page. A jquery solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your popup an id and change its css properties like so:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    let left =   (window.outerWidth - 400) ;
    let top =  (window.outerHeight - 500 );
    let popup= window.open(`mainfolderpath/popup.html`,'Calculator',`left=${left},top=${top},width=400,height=500`); return false;
```